# is it deliver positive influence on "consumers' life" or "consumers' lives"?

Tags: plural-forms

So my writing has "to facilitate the clients’ businesses and deliver a positive influence on consumers’ life."

Should it be consumers' lives or consumers' life?

Is there a difference in the meanings?

Comment: An "influence" isn't really something that can be "delivered." One _exerts_ or _provides_ an influence. It's also a verb: one can _positively influence_ something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a difference in meaning because “life” is grammatically incorrect. It must be “Lives,” as “consumers” is plural.

It could be rewritten so this is not the case.

E.G: “improving consumer life” or “improving the consumer’s life”